# Applying for visa in an embassy in a different country from the one I live in

Tags: applications, saudi-arabia, embassies

Within a few months I'm going to move to Brussels (just suppose I already live there), and I want to apply for KSA visa in order to perform Umrah.

KSA embassies do not issue visas to ordinary people but only through agent. The problem is that there are no agents in Belgium that would just apply for visa for their customers. Instead, they want people to travel with them in a travel group in order to make them pay for the whole Umrah package. I don't want that because it's expensive and I also don't want to share a hotel room with anyone since I trust nobody (it happens that people have their passports stolen). Therefore I'd like to go to London because there there are agents who only apply for visa for a certain fee.

Can I get visa from an embassy in a city I do not live in? Are Saudi authorities going to suspect an attempt of circumvention of their own system (although there's not any) and put me in a flight back home? Am I going to risk something? I honestly think that it is not the case because upon arrival I would show them a visa issued from their own authorities and then there would be no trick here.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship and your immigration status in Belgium?

Comment: As I said, I'm supposed to settle within a few months, so consider me in this question to have already settled in Belgium. I'm a Schengen National, hence It would not be difficult to settle there, this is why I've written in the question to consider this already done.

Comment: Traveller you edited my question 8 hours ago. Are you able to answer?